# Implementação de Log no spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log

Implementei o LOG na minha aplicação Spring Boot porem ela gera arquivos inteiros de vários dias gostaria de particionar por dia teria como ? 
Para fazer a configuração estou usando no meu Properties o seguinte código:

```
logging.path=/home/app/logs/
logging.file=app-api.log
```

e na chamada do log utilizo desta forma :

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductController.class);

@GetMapping(path = "/list-all")
    public List<Product> listAllProduct(){
        try {
            return roductRepository.findAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Erro ao efetuar a busca");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar Logback e o trecho de config seguinte no `logback.xml`:

```
<appender name="TIME_BASED_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/home/app/logs/app-api.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">        
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>/home/app/logs/app-api-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log</fileNamePattern>

    </rollingPolicy>

    ...

</appender>
```

Comment: Ok vou utilizar muito obrigado